# Record -0° temp in Arkansas and my '10 Jeep Grand Cherokee is overheating plus heater stopped working

Tags: coolant, overheating, heater, water-pump, antifreeze

I had a good amount of 50/50 AF but when the temp dropped to record low of -0° my heater gradually went out over several days. I added a little concentrated AF and next day it overheated. Should I replace the water pump? Do I need to flush the coolant? Is concentrated AF bad? 2010 jeep grand Cherokee.

Comment: Was the coolant in the engine 50/50, or does "a good amount" mean some if it was 50/50, and the rest ... something else?  When you ran the engine, did the temp gauge move?

Comment: Have you checked the level? was the existing coolant weak? Did you test it? or just added some "in case"?